# Why is user.getRole() set as the GrantedAuthority in this Spring 3.0 authentication example?

Tags: java, authentication, spring-security

I'm trying to understand Spring 3.0 authentication.

In the code below, why is `user.getRole()` set as the `GrantedAuthority`?

```
public final UserDetails loadUserByUsername(final String username)
{
    final List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
    UserAccount user = (UserAccount) memcacheService.get(username);

    if (user == null)
    {
        final Query query = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT u FROM UserAccount u WHERE username = :username");
        query.setParameter(USERNAME, username);

        try
        {
            user = (UserAccount) query.getSingleResult();

            memcacheService.put(username, user, Expiration.byDeltaSeconds(DEFAULT_EXPIRATION));
        }
        catch (NoResultException e)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

    authorities.add(new GrantedAuthorityImpl(user.getRole()));

    return new EnhancedUser(user.getUsername(), user.getEmail(), user.getDisplayName(), user.getPassword(), user
        .getSalt(), user.isEnabled(), user.isAccountNonExpired(), user.isCredentialsNonExpired(), user.isAccountNonLocked(),
        authorities);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In 3.0 the `UserDetails` object has to maintain the authorities as a list of `GrantedAuthority` implementations. If some complex or custom handling of roles is required, application developers are supposed to write their own implementation of `GrantedAuthority`. But in most cases the authority is simply based on roles defined as String so spring-security out-of-the-box provides a default simple implementation of String role based implementation of `GrantedAuthority` which is `GrantedAuthorityImpl`.

I hope this is what you wanted to know bcz the question is a bit unclear.